# Unix: List files with specific ending and show their size and date

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

I want to use ls -larth but I want to see only files that end with .dmp

find . -name '*.dmp' gives me the results of files, but I cannot see their dates and size. If possible, I would like to have them sorted by date.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Danijel

Comment: Have you tried this ls -larth *.dmp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.dmp' -exec ls -lt {} \;
```

Comment: `-exec ls -lt {} +` (or with `-lth`) would be better here in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ls like this :

```
ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

in file section you can select file with wildcard like '*.dmp'

Then you can use :

```
ls -larth '*.dmp'
```

Comment: The `-h` option is [a non-standard extension to the `ls` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html).

Answer (score 0):

With GNU find:

```
$ find -name "*.dmp" -printf "%t %9s %p\n" 
Wed May 17 14:13:50.0729080492 2017 361758720 ./foo.dmp
Sun May 24 12:34:45.0645200000 2015         2 ./a/bar.dmp
```

See the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for the `-printf` format options.

Sorting is easier if we change the time format to something more logical:

```
$ find -name "*.dmp" -printf "%TF %TT %9s %p\n"  |sort
2015-05-24 12:34:45.6452000000         2 ./a/bar.dmp
2017-05-17 14:13:50.7290804920 361758720 ./foo.dmp
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to get seconds without the fractional part, but we could just drop seconds altogether:

```
$ find -name "*.dmp" -printf "%TF %TH:%TM %9s %p\n"  |sort
2015-05-24 12:34         2 ./a/bar.dmp
2017-05-17 14:13 361758720 ./foo.dmp
```

Or with "human-readable" sizes, with `numfmt` from GNU coreutils:

```
$ find -name "*.dmp" -printf "%TF %TH:%TM %9s %p\n"  |sort |numfmt --field 3 --to=iec
2015-05-24 12:34         2 ./a/bar.dmp
2017-05-17 14:13      345M ./foo.dmp
```